# React Admin: stay on and clear create form on submit

Tags: react-admin

Per the React Admin documentation, you can set the SimpleForm redirect prop to “edit”, “show”, “list”, and false.  Or enter a custom route.

Why not create?

We want to facilitate quickly entering data.  Submit, new form, fill it out, submit.  I've tried setting it to the create route.  In our case something like `/#/adminResource/create` where adminResource is the name of the resource, but what happens is I see the url bar flash to something than to the list route of our first resource.  Not sure what it flashes to, it's to fast to catch.

What am I missing here?

```
const redirect = (basePath, id, data) => {
  return `/#/adminResource/create`;
};

const ResourceCreate = props => (
  <Create title='Create a State' {...props}>
    <SimpleForm redirect={redirect}>
```

[EDIT]  I did try setting redirect to false.  This kept the user on the create form, but the form doesn't reset.  The previous values persist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay in the Create form, try this: `redirect={false}`

Comment: Setting redirect to false remains on the form, and the create route, but does not clear the form.  The previous entries remain.

Comment: Try setting the initial values for the form: <SimpleForm initialValues={ ... } ...